# Cache memory error on motherboard

Tags: motherboard, bios, cache

I am receiving 11 beeps on AMI bios (cache memory error from beeping codes).

The motherboard is an [ASRock CONROE945PL-GLAN](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/ConRoe945PL-GLAN/).

Can anybody help me solve this? I tried resetting RAM and CMOS battery, but computer won't start.

Comment: Is this a new PC build, or was it working fine for a while and then died?

Comment: I successfully solved the problem thanks to Hennes. BTW, it is an old PC.

Answer (score 0):

This motherboard has no cache on the motherboard itself. All cache in it is inside the CPU.

Thus it probably means that your **CPU** has failed. Try re-seating the CPU and check if its cooling is OK.

If that does not solve it, try the motherboard with another, compatible CPU.

Comment: Thanks Hennes. Since I am complete novice in this area, can you please explain to me how should i do this.

Comment: Since you ask this: Maybe not on your own. Still: Open the computer, look at the CPU and the cooler (right side of http://www.asrock.com/mb/photo/ConRoe945PL-GLAN.jpg has the CPU socket). Check if the fan is properly attached. If not, read the manual (found here: ftp://europe.asrock.com/manual/ConRoe945PL-GLAN.pdf ) at page 15. Reverse steps 6 though 1. Check for obvious damage. reinsert CPU (or backup CPU), apply a bit of termal paste, reassemble, retry.

Comment: If you do not feel comfortable with that: ask someone else to do it. It is easy, but also easy to get wrong. (E.g. do not wear a woolen sweater -static-. And do not add too much thermal paste. And only if there is no thermal **pad**). Etc etc.